# mysqlbackup failed with error when --use-tts option is used

Tags: mysql, backup

I just found an interesting behavior when using the mysqlbackup feature to create a backup of a database and I'm wondering if I missed any steps or maybe a config that I missed or created a typo somewhere.

When running the following command:

```bash
/path/to/mysql_enterprise_backup/bin/mysqlbackup --host=127.0.0.1 \
  --user=$BACKUP_USER --password=$BACKUP_PASS --include-tables="^\*.\*$" \
  --with-timestamp --use-tts --backup-dir=$BACKUP_DIR --compress \
  backup-and-apply-log
```

I get an error at the end of the script:

> InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
> 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
> 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
> 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85
> 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99  210120 09:53:45 PCR1
> INFO: We were able to parse ibbackup_logfile up to
> lsn 31466657750. 210120 09:53:45 MAIN    INFO: Apply-log-compress operation completed successfully. 210120 09:53:45
> MAIN    INFO: Full backup prepared for recovery successfully.
>
> MAIN: Can't get stat of
> '/path/to/backup/hotbackups/2021-01-20_09-51-53/datadir/ibdata1'
> (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory) 210120 09:53:45 MAIN ERROR:
> Unable to get the size of file
> /path/to/backup/hotbackups/2021-01-20_09-51-53/datadir/ibdata1. Error
> code: 2, No such file or directory
>
> mysqlbackup failed with errors!

As per the error, the script attempts to get the size of the `ibdata1` file, but it can't find it and fails.

The only items available in the `datadir` directory are my schemas and `ibbackup_logfile`, but not `ibdata1`.

Now this is where it gets interesting and also where I'm getting lost.
I'm using the `--use-tts` option when creating my backup (in order to be selective and restore in another environment) but looking at the [doc for the `--use-tts` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.12/en/backup-partial-options.html#option_meb_use-tts), and I quote:

> The system tablespace is not backed up, saving disk space and I/O
> resources

With this in mind, if I understand correctly, the `--use-tts` option will not backup and create the `ibdata` file but the command `mysqlbackup` will still check for that specific file even though the option to not create it has been specified in the command.

This is causing the backup to get the fail message.

My dilemma at this time is that the `mysqlbackup` command fails even though my backup seems to have been done correctly. (I'm assuming it was done correctly because of this log entry: "210120 09:53:45 MAIN INFO: Full backup prepared for recovery successfully.")

Has anyone noticed this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is some error cause by bad usage of the tool. Make sure you are running a *mysqlbackup* version that is compatible with the server version of MySQL your databases are running. Note that upgrading only either one will not work, so for instance *MySQL* version 8 and older only works with *MySQL Enterprise Backup* 8 or older.

Check from the documentation.

Comment: That is a really good point, but we are running a compatible version, mysql enterprise backup version 4.1.3 and mysql 5.7.28 which as per the documentation, they are compatible https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.1/en/bugs.compatibility.html